# Question of P &C

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are 3 pots and 3 coins. All thesecoins are to be distributed into these pots where any pot can contain any number of coins.

In how many ways all these coins can be distributed such that no pot is empty if all coins are different but all pots are identical ???

Plzzz answer this question as soon as  possible as I have an important exam in a week

Comment: Exactly $1$ way.

Comment: Sorry but the answer is wrong

Comment: Why is the answer wrong?

Comment: 6,ways I think.

Comment: Can u plz explain

Comment: Btw ans is 6 ánd u are right

Comment: $6$ if the pots are different, $1$ if the pots are identical. According to your question they are identical, hence the answer is $1$.

Comment: Let the coins be $1,2,3$.  "All pots are **identical**" implies to me that if we were to rearrange the pots we consider the outcomes the same.  The phrasing suggests to me that the answer of $1$ is the correct answer.  If the question were phrased instead "All pots are **distinct**" then the answer would be $6=3!=3\cdot 2\cdot 1$, seen easily via multiplication principle (choose which pot the first coin goes in: choose which pot the second coin goes in:...).

Comment: My que is right and the correct answer is 6 and it would be a great help if so eone could explain it to me

Comment: Any reason for down voting ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha could be a number of reasons.  "*Plzzz answer soon*" phrases are frowned upon.  The honest truth is that people don't care about op's circumstances.  There is also a distinct lack of effort in attempting to understand the problem shown.  The problem itself is particularly introductory and should not have posed any challenge.  And there is also the OP telling people that they are wrong in the comments despite giving sound and correct answers.

Comment: @JMoravitz You are correct in your reasons,  but this was his first question ever, and i would not except him to know the "etiquette"s. So things like bad formatting, lack of respect to other commentators maybe ignored. About the the difficulty level of question, it should never be a factor as there is no guidelines on the difficulty level of the question to be asked. I understand if this was on MO, but why here ?. If you ask me, down voting this for any reason except lack of effort, is a complete abuse, Even that can be ignored. i prefer giving some advice rather than direct punishment

Answer (score 3):

As with nearly every introductory counting question, we can approach via [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) which paraphrased says:

> Supposing you wish to count the number of possible outcomes of a scenario and you can describe **every** outcome of a scenario **in a unique way** via a sequence of steps such that
>
> - The **number** of choices available at each step does not depend on the previous steps (*the choices themselves may change*)
> - Every outcome is uniquely described via a sequence of choices
>
> then the total number of outcomes is the *product* of the number of choices available at each step.

The question where the three coins are distinct and the three jars are also **distinct**:

- Pick which jar the first coin goes into: $\color{red}{3~ \text{choices}}$
- Pick which jar the second coin goes into: We recognize that the *only* way for all pots to be nonempty is for each pot to get exactly one of the coins.  (*if any pot got two or more coins, there would be a pot without any coins in it at all*).  Therefore, the second coin must go into a **different** pot than the first coin went into.  Whichever pot it was that the first coin went into, there are exactly two available pots for the second coin to go into.  $\color{red}{2~\text{choices}}$
- Pick which jar the third coin goes into: It must be different than the jar used by both the first and second coin by the same logic.  There is only one jar left to use.  $\color{red}{1~\text{choice}}$

The total number of arrangements then with the jars **distinct** will be $\color{red}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 3!=6}$ possibilities.

---

The question where the jars are considered *identical* however is a different problem.  We could approach the same way.

- Pick which jar the first coin goes into: Well... all of the jars are the same, so there is one choice available.  $\color{red}{1~\text{choice}}$
- Pick which jar the second coin goes into: Technically there could be a second possibility here now, we could put the coin into one of the empty jars or we could put it into the jar which has the first coin already in it.  That is the only thing we can tell apart about the jars.  However, via the same logic as before, all jars can only have one coin in it, so the only possibility is that it goes into an empty jar.  Regardless which empty jar was used, we can't tell them apart so we consider these choices to be the same.  $\color{red}{1~\text{choice}}$
- Pick which jar the third coin goes into: Same logic applies: $\color{red}{1~\text{choice}}$

The total number of arrangements with the jars **identical** will be $\color{red}{1\cdot 1\cdot 1 = 1^3 = 1}$ possibility.

Another way of seeing this is by temporarily assuming that the jars are distinct, and recognizing that each and every desired outcome was overcounted by a factor of $3!$.  Dividing by $3!$ allows us to "*forget*" how the jars are labeled, allowing us to then treat them as identical, giving an answer of $\frac{3!}{3!}=1$ outcome again.